# Drupal 7 views of type Services fetches incomplete data

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-services

I have created a Service View using views module, where I have a field body of which the formatted as services raw. It is only showing me the first character in the body string (eg: if body string is "All men must die", It shows "A") shown as folling:

[image: Please refer this screen capture]

I wanted to get the complete text from the field body.
This is also happening if I have an entity reference field where formatter is set to Entity id, It gives me only the first digit of Entity uid (eg: if uid is 16, It shows 1) 
Please help

Comment: may i know is it show properly in your content view page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using PHP 7.1

There's a known issue with the **Services Views** module; and seems like a fix has been committed to `7.x-1.x-dev` branch on December 1, 2017.

I'd recommend reading through the issue #2910966
https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views/issues/2910966

Then, you will have to upgrade to the development branch to fix the issue you are having.

Make sure to backup your files and database before upgrading the module code.

Comment: Thanks @osman , applied the patch and it is now working as expected ! :)